# stylesheet "profiler"

Tags: html, css, profiling

Does anyone know of software or a webservice that can read your stylesheet and html/php, and profile your CSS? By that I mean indicating which clauses or rules are never used, and so on.

After doing several serious redesigns on a fairly complex website, I'm *sure* there are some old skeletons hiding away, making my code clunkier and less readable, doing absolutely nothing, setting rules for divs and spans long since removed.

Comment: Good question. It’s a trickier problem than it sounds: to figure out what style rules aren’t used, a tool would have to scan the stylesheet and every HTML file it’s applied to. There’s no way to know which HTML files it’s applied to, so it could easily flag stuff that’s actually used somewhere, if the person running the tool isn’t familiar with the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ['Dust-Me Selectors' Firefox plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5392/) is quite helpful for finding unused rules, it can test individual pages and spider entire sites.

Comment: Thanks! This is more or less what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

Well, I've found something interesting. Using the "Audits" tool as part of the Chrome developer tools, you can find out which CSS rulesets are extraneous.

[image]

It's quite basic - it doesn't even point to the line number each of these rules are located from, but it is better than nothing. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), the [firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/personal.html) extension. It will tell you what rules aren't being used and which ones are unnecessary.

Comment: +1: Firebug is too good. it strikes out styles which are overridden or not required.

Comment: Firebug will only highlight inheritance, but I believe the OP not only wants that, but also rulesets that are never used at all, which Firebug can't do

Comment: I use firebug a lot, but I really need something that'll go through these massive stylesheets, compare them to the html, and say "cut out these blocks, they don't do anything" and so on

Comment: i didn't know firebug could do this!